# Pass two defferent parameters in URL to filter data

Tags: php, html

I have something like an e-commerce website , where i can filter products by category and by price, views ,date, and likes.
so i made two variables $catig and $sort : the first param takes the name of category and display just products within that category , and the second param filter those products by likes , date , ...

```
 <a href="index.php?catig=computers">Computers</a>
 <a href="index.php?catig=books">Books</a>
 <a href="index.php?catig=software">Software</a>

 <a href="index.php?sort=date">Date</a>
 <a href="index.php?sort=likes">Likes</a>
 <a href="index.php?sort=price">Price</a>
```

my problem here is that for example when i choose in computers as a category this is how the URL look like

> index.php?catig=computers

and if i want to sort those computers by price  this is how the URL look like

> index.php?sort=price

it gives me all products sorted by price , not just computers.
i want if i choose computers and i click on price i want to sort just computers by price. i want the URL look something like this

> index.php?catig=computers&sort=price

so can anyone show me how can i add the second param when the first is set.
this is the php code i'm using :

```
if (isset($_GET['catig'])) {
   $q = $_GET['catig'];
   if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
      $s = $_GET['sort'];
      $sqll = "SELECT * FROM services  WHERE catigory= '$q' ORDER BY $s asc" ; 
   } else {
      $sqll = "SELECT * FROM services  WHERE catigory= '$q' ORDER BY id asc" ; 

} else {
   if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
      $s = $_GET['sort'];
      $sqll = "SELECT * FROM services   ORDER BY $s asc" ; 
   } else {
      $sqll = "SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY id asc " ;
      }   
}
```

Comment: Obviously you have to change your href value for sorting tabs.

Comment: **[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**

Comment: @Godinall how ,can you please show me how

Comment: change your href to pass both index.php?catig=computers&sort=price

Comment: @Vld if i remove the very outer if/else it will give me undefined categ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how much you know about your code, but below solution should work for you.
Include below js:

```
<script>
    function addParam(url, param, value) {
       var a = document.createElement('a'), regex = /[?&]([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
       var params = {}, match, str = []; a.href = url; value=value||"";
       while (match = regex.exec(a.search))
           if (param != match[1]) str.push(match[1] + "=" + match[2]);
       str.push(encodeURIComponent(param) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
       a.search = (a.search.substring(0,1) == "?" ? "" : "?") + str.join("&");
      // return a.href;
       window.location.href = a.href;
    }
</script>
```

Then edit your sorting tabs href value like below:

```
<a href="javascript:addParam(window.location.href, 'sort', 'date');">Date</a>
 <a href="javascript:addParam(window.location.href, 'sort', 'likes');">Likes</a>
 <a href="javascript:addParam(window.location.href, 'sort', 'price');">Price</a>
```

Comment: the error is from  php code . warning mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter 0 given. the URL is correct , but i dont know what's the problem

Comment: i have one more question : i need to click twice on Date or likes to see the result , is there a way that make your code work by clicking just once on date, likes or price. and thanks again for your help

Comment: @user3694409 with limited info above it is really difficult to give a solution, try move the js up to the head part that's all I can say for now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing those Hrefs to radio buttons. Something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="catig" value="computers"> Computers
<input type="radio" name="catig" value="books"> Books
```

plus:

```
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="price"> Price
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="likes"> Likes
```

Then you can get the URL that you are after.